# Visual Studio Code + Vue JS : new folder not detected

Tags: visual-studio-code, vuejs3

I'm tryning to take advantage of vs code auto completion and auto import with Vue JS.
New folders or renamed folders are not detected and. After creating a file in a new folder, I can't import @/newfolder/file or @/components/newfolder/file
I need to reload the window before my new folder can be detected.

When a folder is deleted, its deletion is also not detected.

Has someone encounter and resolve this problem ?

**My settings :**

```
VS Code : 1.79.2 (also tried with v1.80)
Vue Language Features (Volar) : v1.8.4
TypeScript Vue Plugin (Volar) : v1.8.4
@builtin TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features is disable in workspace (VS Code)

Vue : ^3.3.4
Vite : 4.3.9
@vitejs/plugin-vue : ^4.2.3
```

**tsconfig.app.json (referenced in tsconfig.json)**

```
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.dom.json",
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

**vite.config.ts**

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```